# How can I access Windows 8 File History programatically?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-8, .net-4.5

I have several thousand image files that have been corrupted by some rogue process on my machine.  I have some .NET code to discover broken files.  I would like to enumerate and access previous versions of those files (Windows 8 File History is enabled) and restore working versions.

I have found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with information about how to *configure* file history in code, but nothing on **how to access the previous versions in code**.  Is there a straightforward **API for this**?

Comment: Could you explain the close vote?  This is about using the Windows API to access a resource in .NET.  (I'll change the wording to make this clearer if that helps.)

Comment: The close voters felt it was a question for superuser.  I think the edits clarified that you're looking for a programmatic solution so it shouldn't be an issue now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I'd overlooked the obvious.  With file history, backups are written to a configurable location.  I checked my file history drive, and found a directory structure mirroring my source drive.  Multiple versions of each backed up file are present, each with a date and time suffix.  e.g. `mytextfile.txt` has multiple versions with names like `mytextfile (2013_05_15 10_22_00 UTC).txt`.

It was straightforward to match source files with backups using a simple regular expression.  No fancy Win API calls needed.

I'd still be interested to know, for future reference, if there's a more 'scientific' way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Found a sample here: [FileHistory Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/FileHistory-e1d403aa/sourcecode?fileId=51258&pathId=1072678399)

Comment: Thanks.  But really it's a demo of the API for *managing* file history rather than accessing it.

Comment: That link brings up "This item is not yet published."